# Why does stdin.write automatic send EOF?

Tags: python, subprocess

I'm really confused about behavior of subprocess's `stdin.write` method . here is code, and hope someone could help me, thanks.

```
# main.py
import pickle
import subprocess
import sys

p = subprocess.Popen(['python' ,'subpro.py'],stdin=subprocess.PIPE)

dict_sample = {
    'a' : 1,
    'b' : 2
}
bytes_data = pickle.dumps(dict_sample)
p.stdin.write(bytes_data)
p.stdin.write(bytes_data)
p.stdin.write(bytes_data)
```

and another file

```
# subpro.py
import pickle
import sys

def subpro():
    try:
        while True:
            source_bytes = sys.stdin.buffer.read()
            print(pickle.loads(source_bytes))
    except EOFError:
        print('EOFError')
subpro()
```

the output is:

```
{'a': 1, 'b': 2}
b''
```

when I ran `main.py` and realized `p.stdin.write(bytes_data)`will send empty bytes data `b''`. and the loop will break. so I want to know how to send data by pipe on and on?

Comment: So what behaviour are you observing? I doubt it it the `write()` call that sends the EOF; you receive a EOF because the pipe is closed.

Comment: `pickle.loads(source_bytes)` - you misunderstand how the pipe works. Calls to `p.stdin.write` on the sending side do not correspond 1-1 with calls to `sys.stdin.buffer.read` on the receiving side. We're not sending demarcated packets here. When you do `sys.stdin.buffer.read()`, that reads all data until EOF.

Comment: @Martijn Pieters you mean the pipe will closed after it sent a line? I asked this question because I want to practise [`dabeaz's` sample](http://www.dabeaz.com/coroutines/coprocess.py) in python3. so I want to know how to send data by pipe constantly.

Comment: @litbear: I didn't say that. We did ask you to show what you have observed. As user2357112 points out, you are reading *all written data until EOF*. There are no lines here, just data.

Comment: @Martijn Pieters I observed the`EOFError` will raised . But I did not sent EOF explicitly. so I wonder why `EOFError` came out automatically

Comment: @litbear: Because you repeatedly try to read from a pipe. The first `read()` reads *all available data*. The second call then fails, you already read everything. You are assuming that `write()` on one side leads to the same data appearing when using `read()` on the other side. This isn't true. Multiple `write()` calls are combined, a single `read()` reads all available data. Buffering and timing issues come into play too, this isn't simple.

Comment: @Martijn Pieters thank you ! further more how to load pickle data from pipe in python 3 just like [previous link](http://www.dabeaz.com/coroutines/coprocess.py) , could you give me a hand ?

Comment: @litbear: that code uses `picke.load()` which handles the reading. It does so by reading in *steps*, and only as much as needed. It never issues a blanket `.read()`. Perhaps you could try the same.